# requests.json and json.loads() JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert the response I have in a json

```
response = requests.get('http://solr.library.ucla.edu/solr/sheetmusic/select/?q=%5C*%20AND%20(url_keyword:http*)&version=2.2&start=0&rows=100&indent=on&facet=true&facet.field=r_date_facetRange&wt=json&json.wrf=jsonp1530647389471')
response = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
```

But I get back this error

```
~/.virtualenvs/pistache/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py in json(self, **kwargs)
        890                     # used.
        891                     pass
    --> 892         return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
        893 
        894     @property

    /usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
        352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
        353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
    --> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
        355     if cls is None:
        356         cls = JSONDecoder

    /usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
        337 
        338         """
    --> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
        340         end = _w(s, end).end()
        341         if end != len(s):

    /usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
        355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
        356         except StopIteration as err:
    --> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
        358         return obj, end

    JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: That's not JSON. It looks like JSONP.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: this is the error you get when trying to load an empty string. have you verified the response body is not empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must use the same URL without modiying it, you can use `re` module to extract the JSON in the response content of your request like this example:

```
import re, json, requests

url = 'http://solr.library.ucla.edu/solr/sheetmusic/select/?q=%5C*%20AND%20(url_keyword:http*)&version=2.2&start=0&rows=100&indent=on&facet=true&facet.field=r_date_facetRange&wt=json&json.wrf=jsonp1530647389471'

resp = requests.get(url)
resp_parsed = re.sub(r'^jsonp\d+\(|\)\s+$', '', resp.text)
data = json.loads(resp_parsed)
print(data)
```

Otherwise, the other answer is correct and more simple to use.

Comment: Thanks. But don't forget @VictorRodrigues to accept the answer that suits the most to your needs.

Comment: @ChihebNexus It's weird how often I see this on SO. Victor... where you at?! You need to accept an answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

This url returns not JSON, but [JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). In order to parse response you can remove the last parameter (`json.wrf=jsonp1530647389471`) from url - then the response will become JSON and you will be able to parse it with `json.loads`.

```
response = requests.get('http://solr.library.ucla.edu/solr/sheetmusic/select/?q=%5C*%20AND%20(url_keyword:http*)&version=2.2&start=0&rows=100&indent=on&facet=true&facet.field=r_date_facetRange&wt=json')
print json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
# {u'facet_counts': {u'facet_ranges': {}...
```

Or, to make it more simple:

```
response = requests.get('http://solr.library.ucla.edu/solr/sheetmusic/select/?q=%5C*%20AND%20(url_keyword:http*)&version=2.2&start=0&rows=100&indent=on&facet=true&facet.field=r_date_facetRange&wt=json').json()
```

Comment: the requests library's get function has a `.json()` function. So you can use that instead. So instead of your second row: `print(response.json())`

Answer (score 0):

I got decode error because i was reading the data in a loop and connection timed out or ended after few "gets" I tried sleep for few milliseconds to overcome this error

```
    url = "https://api.coindcx.com/exchange/ticker"    
    while(True):
        t.sleep(0.5)
        resp = requests.get(url) 
        resp_parsed = re.sub(r'^jsonp\d+(|)\s+$', '', resp.text)    
        data = json.loads(resp_parsed)
        print(pd.DataFrame(data).query("market=='LINKINR'")['last_price'].values[0])
```